# Eclipse-Can't open in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, eclipse, ide

I downloaded eclipse from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsSKU.png). And tried to open as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt)
. But when I double click or try to open the eclipse using command,

```
./eclipse
```

It shows the following error.[image]

How to resolve this? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You might be using 32-bit Java when you should be running 64-bit. Check the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13).

Comment: @Keidax it was right but vice-versa. I'm using 64 bit Java and 32 bit eclipse. I'll update results after I install 64 bit eclipse.thank you.

Comment: @Keidax Hey is there a way to see the size of the packages I'm downloading while adding ADK packages? Because it will not show even in the log window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `java -version` and see if it says you are running x86 (32bit) or 64 bit java.

If you are running 64 bit Java, you need to re-download the 64 bit version of Eclipse.  Your error shows -arch x86 (meaning it wants a 32 bit OS/Java)

Why don't you use the Eclipse from the software center?  It's much easier to install.  You are, however, more than welcome to install from source, or a downloaded deb :)

Comment: Its about 300+ Mb's of software and I don't like to download again if I reinstall my OS with other version and when installed from software center it will install only inside system directory but here I can install the software wherever I can. Since there are so many softwares like this that has to be downloaded, I prefer downloading their installation files for permanent usage.

Comment: Hey is there a way to see the size of the packages I'm downloading while adding ADK packages? Because it will not show even in the log window.